# For me the letters D, N, A are the fragments of an overheard conversation, incompletely understood

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here Penny McCarthy is talking about her memories of his father working with other famous scientists on DNA studies decades ago:

> My father worked alongside Watson and Crick in the 1960s. He has
> stories about the discovery of the double helix, stories about
> scientists who plunder other scientists’ research, stories about Crick
> and his flirtation with my mother, stories about parties and ladies
> jumping out of cakes for Crick’s birthday, stories about Watson always
> tripping over his shoelaces. Throughout the 1960s and 1970s my father
> worked on DNA so as a child my life sort of fitted in around this
> obsession. In our house his clones lived in the fridge and in
> searching for the butter you always ran the risk of knocking them
> over. **For me the letters D, N, A are the fragments of an overheard
> conversation, incompletely understood.**

([Penny McCarthy](http://www.wellcome.ac.uk/en/fourplus/art_p_mccarthy.html))

Does when she says **"For me the letters D, N, A are the fragments of an overheard conversation, incompletely understood."** imply that:

1. She unintentionally listened to the conversations between her father and his colleagues on DNA related subjects without completely understanding what they were actually talking about. And whenever she hears the word DNA the first thing she remembers is those conversations?

   Or
2. Is it a metaphor for the fact that subjects related to DNA are nonsense for her today?

Comment: Can you take some cues from the formatting I did on your earlier question and apply them here? Speaking strictly visually, the impression this question gives is being an impenetrable, inaccessible wall of text.

Comment: Don't *K*now Answers.

Comment: @Dan Bron  Does it look OK now?

Comment: @user127733 Definitely better. I'd also suggest you enumerate your two possible interpretations, as you did before, to make them stand out better.

Comment: @Dan Bron  :) I am just learning! The +1 was really encouraging! I appreciate it  :D

Comment: I was hoping someone else would dive in so that your entire interpretation of Art & Science isn't dependent on my personal bias, but since no one has and you put a lot of work into the question: your first interpretation is likely why she meant. Also, you're getting really good at this.

Answer (score 2):

I will provide my own interpretation, which is always a hazardous activity.

The analysis of DNA was, as the writer puts it, an obsession of her father, to the point that samples cluttered the family refrigerator. As a child, she had no idea of what obsessed her father, but she knew that it did.

So her childhood memories include snippets of information about the interaction of her father and the subject of DNA, which she likens to an overheard conversation. She knew that the subject was important to her father, but she could make no sense of what her father talked about - "fragments of an overheard conversation".